# plpgsqlでrecordのカラムを動的に指定してその値を書き換えたい

Tags: sql, postgresql

before triggerを用いてupdateを禁止したりdefault値をinsertしたりしたい。

```
create or replace function not_update() returns trigger as $$
begin
  execute format('new.%I = old.%I',  TG_ARGV[0], TG_ARGV[0]);
  return new;
end
$$ language plpgsql security definer;
```

これは試したがシンタックスエラーを吐いた

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-- トリガーハンドラをつくる trigger_not_update参照
create or replace function not_update(col text) returns void as $$
begin
  execute format(
    'create or replace function not_update_%s() returns trigger as $_$'
    'begin'
    '  raise warning ''%% %%'', current_user, session_user;'
    '  if current_user = session_user then' -- superuser can update
    '    return new;'
    '  end if;'
    '  new.%I = old.%I;'
    '  return new;'
    'end'
    '$_$ language plpgsql security definer;', $1, $1, $1);
end
$$ language plpgsql security definer;

-- トリガーハンドラをつくる trigger_insert_default参照
create or replace function insert_default(tabl text, col text) returns void as $$
begin
  execute format(
    'create or replace function insert_default_%1$s_%2$s() returns trigger as $_$'
    'declare'
    '  vt text;'
    '  vr record;'
    'begin'
    '  raise warning ''%% %%'', current_user, session_user;'
    '  if current_user = session_user then' -- superuser can insert anything
    '    return new;'
    '  end if;'
    '  select pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid) from pg_attribute a'
    '    left join pg_attrdef d on a.attnum = d.adnum and a.attrelid = d.adrelid'
    '    where a.attrelid = ''data.%1$s''::regclass and a.attnum > 0 and a.attname = %2$L'
    '  into vt;' -- default値を表すtext
    '  execute format(''select %%s as v'', vt) into vr;' -- default値
    '  new.%2$s = vr.v;'
    '  return new;'
    'end'
    '$_$ language plpgsql security definer;', $1, $2);
end
$$ language plpgsql security definer;


create or replace function trigger_not_update(tabl text, col text) returns void as $$
begin
  execute format('select not_update(%L);', $2);
  execute format(
    'create trigger %s_not_update_%s '
    'before update on %I '
    'for each row execute procedure not_update_%s();', $1, $2, $1, $2);
end
$$ language plpgsql security definer;

create or replace function trigger_insert_default(tabl text, col text) returns void as $$
begin
  execute format('select insert_default(%L, %L);', $1, $2);
  execute format(
    'create trigger %1$s_insert_default_%2$s '
    'before insert on %1$I '
    'for each row execute procedure insert_default_%1$s_%2$s();', $1, $2);
end
$$ language plpgsql security definer;

create or replace function trigger_default(tabl text, col text) returns void as $$
begin
  execute format('select trigger_not_update(%L, %L);', $1, $2);
  execute format('select trigger_insert_default(%L, %L);', $1, $2);
end
$$ language plpgsql security definer;

select trigger_default('users', 'id');
select trigger_default('users', 'created');
```